# Can KVMs for 3 monitors & USB keyboard/mouse be used in a mixed Mac/PC environment?

Tags: mac, laptop, desktop-computer, kvm-switch, thunderbolt

Is it possible to use three Thunderbolt displays on multiple computers (mixed environment of PCs and Macs)?  I've used KVMs in other PC-only environments, but I am trying to find out if both PCs and Macs can use three Thunderbolt displays at once, with the ability to switch between the machines.

Comment: Do you just want to know if it is possible, or are you looking for more complete information, like are there specs that determine whether specific combinations will work, or potential issues?

Comment: The reason I didn't have this information on the question was because originally when I did, the question got denied due to being to specific to my situation.  One PC laptop, HP ProBook 640 G1, one MacBook Pro laptop, and two servers (I didn't purchase yet, so open for suggestions.. even Mac server would work).  Thank you for any help you can provide!